# jQuery: Swapping divs containing embedded video

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a page with a grid of thumbnails. Some thumbs open an image, some open an embedded video, all open into a Bootstrap3 modal. To try and “kill” a video that is still playing after a modal is dismissed / hidden I have been trying a few jquery functions (empty, remove) which work just fine, until I have to re-open or open another modal, so now I’m doing a little bit of swapping divs around with replaceWith which also works exactly as intended with photos and with youtube embeds, but not with Instagram video embeds. I can only get 1 successful IG video load per page refresh. Any subsequent calls to an IG embed doesn’t seem to make a connection to IG. Here is a sample of where I am currently at:

```
<a id="myButton" role="button" onclick="showEmbed(0);">CLICK ME (0)</a>
<a id="myButton" role="button" onclick="showEmbed(1);">CLICK ME (1)</a>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="inner"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
<script>
    var showEmbed = function(id) {

      var embed = instagram[id]['embed'];  // grab the IG embed from array
      var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));  // create newDiv
      newDiv.attr('id', `newDiv${ id }`);  // add distinct ID to newDiv
      newDiv.append(embed);  // add the embed to the newDiv
      $('#inner').replaceWith(newDiv); // replace placeholder div with newDiv
      $('#myModal').modal('show');  // show the modal


      $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        var inner = $(document.createElement('div'));  // on modal dismiss, remake placeholder div
        inner.attr('id', "inner"); 
        newDiv.replaceWith(inner); // replace the above created newDiv with the recreated placeholder div
      });

    }
  </script>
```

**Here it was it looks like as it happens:**

1) You can see the empty div #inner before any modals are activated:
[image: 1st screenshot]

2) #inner is replaced by #newDiv0 which now has the embed code in it (this displays properly):
[image: 2nd screenshot]

3) Once modal is dismissed, #inner is recreated and replaces #newDiv0 as the modal is hidden:
[image: 3rd screenshot]

4) Just like in step2, #inner is again replaced but now with #newDiv1 (which is also an IG video embed), however this time the iframe is missing and the network tab shows no connection to Instagram:
[image]

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work and maybe suggest a workaround? Thank you for reading, I know this is a lengthy post.

Comment: Can you console.log(id) in that switch function, are you passing in the same id twice?

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks for helping - I am passing the ID once which gets used to locate the embed record and create a unique div ID. Here is a plnkr link where I have this available:


http://plnkr.co/edit/oEJVoZdAF8F2bMavPXtS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get that [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/r8t8W2b9oJCyh2exbAB3?p=preview) to work. A few things.

1. Include the embed script only once in the body.

   > < script src="https://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js">
2. Add the window.instgrm call below as the last line in your switch function.

   ```
    $('#myModal').modal('show');  // show the modal
    window.instgrm.Embeds.process();
   ```
3. Remove the `embed.js` script from all of your embed items.
4. Optionally add `OMITSCRIPT=true` to your embed links (so the embed.js does not load for each item).